# How to fix 'green screen' issue on Windows Movie Maker?

Tags: windows, video-editing, windows-movie-maker

In Windows 10 Home, Version 1803 I am using Windows Movie Maker, version 2012, Build 16.4.3528.0331. When I drag-and-drop AVI videos to the timeline it happens that these videos only show a green screen. The video is not shown, but just a green area. However, when just opening the original AVI video outside of the Movie Maker, the correct video is shown (which is not just a green screen).

I tried to install a newer version of Windows Movie Maker (Movie Maker 10 @ moviemaker.support), but either this is something completely different, and this version is not working at all (Even unable to play a clip!!).

So how can I fix this 'green screen' problem with Windows Movie Maker, so that I can edit movies?

Alternatively: Is there a similar free tool available to simple video editing for Windows 10 Home?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has abandoned Windows Movie Creator, which is no longer included
in Windows 10.

It is now replaced by Story Remix and is included in the Windows Photos app,
supposedly already installed if your Windows 10 is up to date.

No point in installing the Windows Movie Creator.

Comment: How to open 'Story Remix'. Never heard of it nor seen it?

Comment: You open the Photos app.